# Doctrine to find parent records

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I am using [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) as follows

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="PersonRepository")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "owner" = "Owner"})
 */
abstract class Person
{
    private $someProperty;
    // ...
}

/** @Entity(repositoryClass="EmployeeRepository") */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity(repositoryClass="OwnerRepository") */
class Owner extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

I also have repositories for each entity.  How can I make `EmployeeRepository::getSomething(1)` return all People (i.e. Employees and Owners) where `someProperty` is equal to 1, and not just all Employees?

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Repository;

abstract class PersonRepository
{
    public function getSomething($someProperty)
    {
        //Desire is to return both Employees and Owners 
        return $this->findBy(['someProperty'=>$someProperty]);
    }
}

class EmployeeRepository extends PersonRepository
{
    public function getSomething($someProperty)
    {
        if($someProperty==123) {
            //Do something
        }
        else return parent::getSomething($someProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't  you use the PersonRepository ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI  I thought that same thing, and tried `self::findBy()` and `parent::findBy()` (which just seems wrong) within `PersonRepository`, but it obviously didn't work.  I "could" create a new instance, but that doesn't make sense and will just use some DQL instead.  Was hoping that `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` might have some `getParent()` method but it doesn't.  Note that I need to start with the child repository as I tried to indicate with `if($someProperty==123)` condition check.

Comment: "I am using Class Table Inheritance as follows" -> no, you are not. Please note that the Class Table Inheritance do not allow abstract classes, only Mapped superclasses does.

Comment: @b.enoit.be  I really am.  I use xml and not annotations for metadata, and only used annotations here as most people use them so maybe did a typo.  Why do you think an abstract class isn't allowed?  Thanks

Comment: Because 1/ it is not documented 2/ it does not allow you to do what you are looking for 3/ it is not coherent with the fact that you do have the class `Person` as a discriminatory column, which makes no sense if the class is abstract and you cannot instantiate it

Comment: @b.enoit.be  `3/`  Agree.  I meant to say Employee.